# What happened to the Mondoshawan trapped in the chamber of the elements?

Tags: the-fifth-element

In the Fifth Element, in 1914 the Mondoshawans collect the stones and the Fifth Element from the chamber of the elements.

As they are leaving, Luke Perry shoots their leader, leading to it being trapped in the chamber.  It is only able to pass the key to the human priest.

300 years later, evil returns.  When Bruce Willis and company go to the chamber to activate the five elements and defeat the evil.

But when they open the door, there is no sign of the trapped Mondoshawan.  It was wearing metal armour (or was a being made of metal), so there should still at least be a husk.

**What happened to the trapped Mondoshawan leader?**

Comment: How sure are we that no one visited the chamber in 300 years? If he's a trapped _leader_, I would assume his people would come back to get him.

Comment: While Bruce Willis and the priest were looking for stones, priest's apprentice was preparing the chamber of the elements (there are light fixtures already set up when Bruce Willis brings Milla Jovovich in). I guess the apprentice removed the body while he was waiting for them.

Comment: I think you guys are on to something resembling a proper answer here.  Also, wasn't Leeloo created by extracting DNA from the remains of that very same Mondoshawan?  I seem to recall the scientists having the severed arm at any rate.  If somebody went back for the arm, logically they could have pried open the door (there's part of an arm squished in it so it's not *fully closed*) and either collected or disposed of the rest of the body as well.

Comment: @Steve-O Leeloo was created by reconstituting the remains of the fifth element, which was in the Mondoshawan ship shot down at the beginning.

Comment: @MrScapegrace Hmmm that's a good point. I forgot that the priest sends his assistant to prepare the temple.

Answer (score 12):

As stated in the comments,

### Cornelius's assistant, David, went to the temple early and prepared the chamber.

Per the script; at the "spaceport?" after Korbin (Bruce Willis) took back his ticket from David, David went to the bar...

> *Cornelius turns to David.*
>
> CORNELIUS: Where's Leeloo?
>
> DAVID: On the plane... with Mr. Dallas... the real one.
>
> CORNELIUS: It's all my fault.  I'm the servant... It's my mission! Here!
>
> *He hands David the Temple Key from around his neck.*
>
> CORNELIUS: Here's the key to the Temple.. **Prepare for our arrival!**

He had the time to add lighting to the room. Surely, he had the time to sweep away whatever was left over of the Mondoshawan.

Comment: Congratulations, this is the winner of the [monthly answer challenge](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4417/49).

Answer (score 1):

The priest took the key. Its likely he either opened the wall at some point to free them, or they died over time with another priest returning with a crew to clean up the interior area after the ship had left.

If the wall could be opened without having to wait thousands of years, then he could have done this anytime. Free them, they call home, everyone's happy. Otherwise, the trapped ones would have passed on, possibly either turning to dust, or they might have laid to rest in a corner of the interior room. If the room itself shrinks to the 4 pillars after the wall shuts, then it would have just crushed them all into nothing.

We don't know what happens after the ship leaves because we move to the future. They could have returned 5 min later saying where is Daryl, Daryl, and his brother Daryl? The ominous music indicates they had a bad fate though, like 500 years later a priest comes to investigate finding the forgotten dead and burying them.